# How can I make ticks appear green?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, jestjs, nestjs

I'm running Jest with Dockerised NestJS in the VS Code terminal.

My tests are passing, but the ticks are grey when using the `--verbose` flag (see image):

[image]

Does anyone know of any way to convert them to green?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it with `--colors` flag, like
`npx jest --verbose --colors`